# why do I have to link against opengl32.lib

Tags: c++, windows, opengl

I'm using modern openGL 3.3. The libraries are glfw-3.1.1 for the window and glew-1.12.0 for the OpenGL content. I've built all libs with visual studio 2012. Basically everything is running however, once I use this line `glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);`, it throws out this error

```
main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__glDrawArrays@12 referenced in function _main
test.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\BIN\cl.EXE"' : return code '0x2'
```

Once I link against `opengl32.lib`, it worked. My question is when I use OpenGL in Windows, do I have always to link against the preceding lib.

Comment: Are those libs from MSYS2?

Comment: Are you really asking why you have to link to the library that provides the function you're trying to use?

Comment: What you are actually asking is "if I use a function from a library do I have to link with that library"?  The answer is " yes".

Comment: @NicolBolas, as I said, I'm using modern OpenGL with GLEW. I thought it is not a good idea to utilize  deprecated OpenGL functions.  I'm not asking from pure C++ perspective. NO. Actually I'm surprised with the linking error which doesn't show up in Mac or Linux.

Comment: @WilliamKappler, what is MSYS2?

Comment: @CroCo: 1) `glDrawArrays` is neither deprecated nor removed. 2) Whether you're using "deprecated" (I dunna think that word means what you think it means) functions or not, you still have to link to `opengl32.lib` and its corresponding .dll if you want to use OpenGL on Windows. Not unless you plan to load each vendor's driver separately.

Comment: @CroCo It's sort of like reverse WINE: kinda a packaging of Linux libraries for Windows. I am figuring that's probably a "no".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`glDrawArrays` is an *old* function. It's been part ever since OpenGL-1.1 introduced vertex arrays so it's been there since the beginning, 20 years ago. As such it's not part of anything that's exposed through the extension mechanism, but through the good old `opengl32.dll` – which BTW you always have to link against if you want to use OpenGL. Some OpenGL loaders will do it for you behind the scenes, but if you're using OpenGL in Windows, you always link against `opengl32.dll`

Comment: Thank you for this informative answer. In `"glew.h"` this function `glDrawArrays` is defined. Why do I have to link against something old?

Comment: @CroCo: Because it's not defined in "glew.h" but merely *declared*. Header files only contain *declarations* of what the compiler may assume to be available to the final program. But the actual definition is not contained in a header file. "glew.h" contains that declaration as a courtsey. It's not GLEW's job to give you `glDrawArrays`. GLEW's job is to give you anything that came *after* OpenGL-1.1 and nothing else. But "glew.h" itself is not giving you anything at all.

Answer (score 0):

I think the confusion here comes from wanting to use OpenGL 3.3, but in doing so linking to opengl32.lib.

The 32 here isn't a version number, it is from WIN32, the name of the Windows C / C++ API.

Comment: no not really. Even if I use OpenGL 4.3, it still throws out the preceding error.